# Run jQuery on page load with values from fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm passing values from one page to another by posting them and then putting them in to hidden fields on the next page. I've tried using the initial values and that doesn't work either, so my assumption is that it's to do with the jquery not checking for initial values. This is what I want to run:

```
function check() {
    var Q1 = $("#question1").val();
    if (Q1 == 'yes') {
        $(".A1").css("display", "block");
    } else { 
        $(".A1").css("display", "none"); 
    }
```

Where #question1 is the ID of the field populated from the previous page, but how do I get the check function to run when the page has loaded? I've tried adding:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    check();
</script>
```

To the bottom of the page with no success, the only way it works at the moment is by clicking a button with this applied:

```
$(".theanswer").click(function() {
    check();
    return false;
});
```

I'm sure there's probably a simple way i'm unaware of so any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `check()` function uses jQuery to retrieve elements. Because of this, you need to run the function after the DOM has been loaded. To do that, place the call to `check()` within a DOM ready event handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        check();  
    });
</script>
```

Also, you can simplify the `check()` function:

```
function check() {
    $('.A1').css('display', $('#question1').val() == 'yes' ? 'block' : 'none');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I know that should work, but it's not. I tried adding the following:

<a href="#" onclick="check(); return false;">Whatever</a>

But this is also not running the check function. It only seems to be called when going through the question buttons.

Comment: All sorted. I had all of my code in my js file wrapped in a document ready script, which i'm guessing affects other functions? Think it's all working now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Warp it the call to check function in document.ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
check();
})    

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a js file and link it you your html page

JS File

```
$(document).ready(function(){
check();
});

function check() 
{
    var Q1 = $("#question1").val();

    if (Q1 == 'yes') 
    {        
        $(".A1").css("display", "block");
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $(".A1").css("display", "none"); 
    }
}
```

Html link

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="yourjsfilename.js"></script>
```